# Added public key but ssh doesn't work with it

Tags: linux, ssh

I added in my public key from my computer to a remote linux server. However, when I try ssh'ing in, it recognize

```
$ ssh -i ./id_rsa david@123.123.123.123.
debug1: Found key in /Users/david/.ssh/known_hosts:189
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: ./id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
david@123.123.123.123's password:
```

Any idea what the issue is here, and how I can ssh to this host without entering a password?

Comment: On remote host your public key is stored in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` ?  Permissions are `700` for `~/.ssh` and `600` for  `authorized_keys`?

Comment: server logs should provide more information.